# Which software can I use to model a nanotube with a triangular lattice shape and extract from it the lammps input file?

Tags: software-recommendations, lammps, software-input-file-request, nanostructures

I am looking for a software to build my own chice of lattice nanotube and get the lammps input file for it.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your nanotube with the recent versions of the [CRYSTAL](https://www.crystal.unito.it) code (see [their tutorial](http://tutorials.crystalsolutions.eu/tutorial.html?td=nanotube&tf=nanotube)). Using the [pycrystal](https://github.com/tilde-lab/pycrystal) Python library you then extract an [ASE Atoms object](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase) and [convert it](https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/blob/master/ase/io/lammpsdata.py) into the LAMMPS input format.